# Passing data from opened window

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, oauth, window.open

I've been stuck on this problem for a day now and was wondering if there's a way I could go about this.

**client side**

Client side is going to be dynamic since it's an app type plugin.
The client side will open up a popup for oAuth purposes. Let's say its domain is `www.google.com`
I have the popup written like `window.open('www.backend.com/api')` in ReactJS.

The client button is something like this:

```
<button onClick={() => iveBeenClicked()}> sync up </button>
```

and then it runs this function

```
const iveBeenClicked = (e) => {
e.preventDefault()
const popupWindow = window.open('www.backend.com/api', "_blank")

}
```

**oAuth and backend with ExpressJS**

This is the backend which we'll say is `www.backend.com/api`

```
router.use("/api", (req, res) => {

  if (req.query.code) {
   res.send(res.query.code)
  } else {
    res.redirect(
      `www.ApiRouteThatRedirectsWhenComplete.com`
    );
  }
});
```

Well I have the code I want, but how can I send that to the client from a different domain? If there's an alternative to `window.open()` where a user could press accept, please let me know.

So the big question is, how can client receive data from window.open's popup?

Thank you in advance!

#EDIT

So I finally got it thanks to @vishal-bartakke 's suggestion which I realized I implemented it wrong. I'm going to supply it here just in case it will help anyone that comes across this post.

for the ivebeenclicked() function in client side:

```
const iveBeenClicked = (e) => {
e.preventDefault()
const popupWindow = window.open('www.backend.com/api', "_blank")

//this is the part that was needed to receive the information of success
window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
if (e.data) {
//do what you need to do with that key
}
})
}
```

in my expressjs's file:

```
router.use(['/api/', '/api/page?'], (req, res) => {

  if (req.query.token) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname +'/thatHTMLpage.html'))
  } else {
    res.redirect(`that route that does the oauth`)
  }
})
```

In that html created upon success, I added this code to send in the data

```
      window.onload = function () {
        let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        window.opener.postMessage(urlParams.get("code"), "*");
      };
```

It is quite a messy setup but it works how I want it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use postMessage [(check here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate between windows. In child window you can refer parent window as `window.opener` for posting message and in parent window you have `popupWindow` for posting

Comment: Thank you! I visited this yesterday and I had trouble getting it to work (maybe it's because I was burned out) but I'm getting some progress now.